# Как передать информацию элемента QListWidget в новое окно

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Я новичок в *Qt* и *C++*, сейчас пытаюсь сделать простой  *GUI* интерфейс.

Есть `QListWidget`, в который в виде списка занесена некоторая информация. Необходимо, чтобы при выборе элемента списка и нажатии на определенную кнопку открывалось новое окно, которое бы отображало информацию данного элемента и при необходимости её изменяла.

Сейчас я могу только открыть новое окно, но не понимаю, как передать в него информацию по выбранному элементу. Есть мысль использовать метод `currentItem`, но как его реализовать — без понятия.

Comment: " списка занесена некоторая информация" Какого рода информация? Просто текст или у вас там что-то сложнее?

Comment: @Unick да, простой текст

Comment: А если вызвать currentItem()->text(), то это будет то что вам надо?

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит изобретать велосипед, ведь есть сигнал [`QListWidget::currentItemChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentItemChanged).

Если вам нужны сложные модели, то стоит смотреть на [`QListView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) и [`QAbstractListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) (*[Qt Model-View Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html)*)

Answer (score 0):

По сигналу `QListWidget::currentItemChanged(QListWidgetItem*,QListWidgetItem*)` передавайте `item->text()` в нужный вам виджет для отображения и обработки. Так же обратно: см. мой пример - по сигналу `QLineEdit::textChanged(QString)` новый текст заменяет старый у `currentItem`.

Пример:

```
class Handler : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

private:
  QListWidget* m_list;
  QLineEdit* m_edit;

public:
  explicit Handler(QWidget* parent = 0) :
    QWidget(parent),
    m_list(new QListWidget(this)),
    m_edit(new QLineEdit(this))
  {
    setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
    layout()->addWidget(m_list);
    layout()->addWidget(m_edit);
    connect(m_list, SIGNAL(currentItemChanged(QListWidgetItem*,QListWidgetItem*)),
            this, SLOT(slotSetEditedItem(QListWidgetItem*)));
    connect(m_edit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString&)),
            this, SLOT(slotSetNewText(const QString&)));
  }

  void addString(const QString& str)
  {
    m_list->addItem(str);
  }

private slots:
  void slotSetEditedItem(QListWidgetItem* current)
  {
    m_edit->setText(current->text());
  }

  void slotSetNewText(const QString& txt)
  {
    if (m_list->currentItem() != 0)
      m_list->currentItem()->setText(txt);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Handler wgt;
  wgt.addString("qwerty");
  wgt.addString("123456");
  wgt.addString("/.,!-+");
  wgt.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```